# How to scaffold controller to a domain class from plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, scaffolding

I installed a plugin and want to scaffold a domain class from the plugin. For my project-own domain classes `Foo` I add `scaffold = true` to `FooController`. If I try this it shows up in the list of controllers but there are no views generated (404 error). I imported the class inside the controller.

Any idea what is wrong or how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to scaffold using class name:

```
static scaffold = DomainClassFromPlugin
```

Comment: I tried and the error message change from `Cannot generate controller logic for scaffolded class true. It is not a domain class!`
to
`No signature of method: com.grailsrock.taxonomy.TaxonController.propertyMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: propertyMissing(java.lang.String)`

Comment: @skurt do you have a persistence plugin (e.g. hibernate or mongodb) installed into your app? I've had bizarre MissingMethodExceptions like these in the past from running a plugin project standalone (because plugins don't normally include hibernate in their BuildConfig).

Comment: Yes hibernate 2.1.1 as default with grails 2.1.1. Is there some way to add this to the plugin afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the plugin editor, you should be able to add the scaffolding plugin in your BuildConfig.groovy

```
  compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
```

then should be to run your **generate** or **generate-all** commands against the domain class to have the controller and/or views created.

Now If you do do not have access to the plugin source, from the app that uses the plugin that has the domains that you want to scaffold I do not think you will be able to. You will have to code that yourself.